# Running linear regression on imported .xlsx dataset returning every row of the column as coefficients instead of just the column name

Tags: r, lm

Say I have the dummy dataset (not the real one I'm using but similar construction):

| Room_Count | Markers_Used | Crayons_Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 0.45 | 242.2 |
| 14 | 0.11 | 212.7 |
| 11 | 4.32 | 74.5 |

When I run the R code:

```
m <- lm(Room_Count ~ Markers_Used + Crayons_Used)
```

I'm getting from in the output of `summary(m)`:

```
Coefficients: 

(Intercept)

Markers_Used0.45

Markers_Used0.11

Markers_Used4.32

Crayons_Used
```

The Crayons_Used intercept is returned as I would expect with just the column name and pertinent stat info. The Markers_Used one is returning the rows of the table as intercepts when I just want Markers_Used to be returned.

Comment: It sounds like your data was imported as strings rather than numeric values. Go back to your import stage and check the `class()` of all your data. You likely have non-numeric values in there or something. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What you have provided does not produce the output you've shown.

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks